# Unable to assign elements to the std::map. showing null values

Tags: dictionary, iterator

I am reading a json file containing Family details and I am tru=ying to fill them in a std::map.  somehow the keys are accepting data but the values are showing null.  please help.

### Code: main.c

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <conio.h>

#include "nlohmann\json.hpp"
#include "extmodule.h"

using namespace std;
using json = nlohmann::json;

FAMILY tempFamily;
CHILD tempChild;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream f("sample.json");
    json data = json::parse(f);

    // Total nof items in 'family' is the no of records
    int noOfRecords = data["family"].size();
    

    for (int fIndex = 0; fIndex < noOfRecords; fIndex++)
    {
        int fId = 0;
        // read the family id from json data object and use the ID as main map key
        data["family"][fIndex]["fId"].get_to(fId);

        // fill the Parent node First        
        data["family"][fIndex]["fName"].get_to(tempFamily.parent.fatherName);
        data["family"][fIndex]["fAge"].get_to(tempFamily.parent.fatherAge);
        data["family"][fIndex]["mName"].get_to(tempFamily.parent.motherName);
        data["family"][fIndex]["mAge"].get_to(tempFamily.parent.motherAge);     

        // fill the child Node 
        int noOfChildren = data["family"][fIndex]["children"].size();
        rec[fId].NoOfChildren = noOfChildren;

        // cout << noOfChildren <<endl;
        for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < noOfChildren; cIndex++)
        {
            int cId = 0;
            data["family"][fIndex]["children"][cIndex]["cId"].get_to(cId);

            data["family"][fIndex]["children"][cIndex]["cName"].get_to(tempChild.childName);
            data["family"][fIndex]["children"][cIndex]["cAge"].get_to(tempChild.childAge);

            tempFamily.child.insert(make_pair(cId, tempChild));
        }
        rec.insert(make_pair(fId, tempFamily));     
    }   
    map<int, FAMILY>::iterator fIt = rec.begin();

     while (fIt != rec.end())
    {
        FAMILY temp;
        std::cout << "Family ID: " << fIt->first <<endl;
        temp= fIt->second;
        std::cout << "Father Name: " << temp.parent.fatherName <<"\t" << fIt->second.parent.fatherAge <<endl;
        std::cout << "Mother Name: " << fIt->second.parent.motherName <<"\t" << fIt->second.parent.motherAge <<endl;
        std::cout << "\tNo of Children: "<< fIt->second.NoOfChildren<<endl;
        std::cout << "\t--------------\n\t";

        map <int, CHILD>::iterator cIt = fIt->second.child.begin();
        while (cIt != fIt->second.child.end())
        {
            std::cout <<"Child ID: "<< cIt->first;
            std::cout <<"\tName : "<< cIt->second.childName <<"\t"<<cIt->second.childAge <<endl;
            ++cIt;

        }
        std::cout <<"--------------------------------------------\n";
        ++fIt;
    }     

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

### Code: extmodule.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

// PARENT Node Structure.

typedef struct
{
    string fatherName;
    int fatherAge;
    string motherName;
    int motherAge;
}PARENT;

//Child Node
typedef struct
{
    string childName;
    int childAge;
}CHILD;

// FAMILY Structure
typedef struct
{
    PARENT parent;
    int NoOfChildren;
    map <int, CHILD> child;
}FAMILY;

//Data Record Map

map <int, FAMILY> rec;
```

tempFamily Structure is getting filled but when using make_pair() to insert element into map it is not assigned.